# Mysql select from two table

Tags: php, mysql

i have two DB table call_pools and blacklists, select query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM call_pools
WHERE queue_name = 'zimba_P'
ORDER BY processed_date DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

Need add select from blacklists and return in existing query value is_blocked = 0 if phone not exists in blacklists and is_blocked = 1 if exsists

Can someone help me, and create an optimized query?

Comment: `Can someone help me, create optimized query` ... I don't think we can help you with _any_ query because both the schema and sample data from the second table are missing.  That being said, can you include this information in your question?

Comment: We are not an oracle. Provide your table structures in a clear way.

Comment: Edit your question with the table schema other ways we cant help you.

Comment: New query
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, (SELECT COUNT(callerid) FROM asterisk.blacklist WHERE callerid = phonenumber) AS is_blocked FROM asterisk.call_pools WHERE queue_name = 'zimba_P' ORDER BY processed_date DESC LIMIT 0,25


But i'm not sure in best performance of this query

Comment: In best way Is_blocked must be 0 or 1, but in this query this count may be more then 1